# PHP: word definition script?

Tags: php, api, dictionary, definition

I am developing a web page on which I am accepting input words from the user, and when the user submits those words, I want to display definition of those words, or wikipedia links of those words for more definition about that word -- something like the following:

Let's say user enetered 5 words:

```
toast, egg, beans, coffee, tea
```

Now I want to display them like:

```
toast  › slices of bread that have been toasted
egg    › animal reproductive body consisting of an ovum or embryotogether with nutritive and protective envelopes
beans  › a small skullcap <link to wikipedia>read more on wikipedia</link>
coffee › a beverage consisting of an infusion of ground coffee beans
tea    › a beverage made by steeping tea leaves in water <link to wikipedia>read more on wikipedia</link>
```

For those words for which there is no article on wikipedia, no wiki link would be displayed.

Can someone please suggest me some open-source PHP script or package that would do this for me?  Alternatively, I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to do this in PHP.

I am more interested in getting data from some other website directly than I am in storing word definitions in my database.

I am using PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explode user's sanitized input into single words by using [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function and then use [Wikipedia API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) (*see [api.php](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php)*) to get definitions or wiki links.
There should be other web services apart from Wikipedia which is providing API access, just Google them. Also [this](http://www.labnol.org/internet/tools/using-wikipedia-api-demo-source-code-example/3076/) could be a good guide if you want to make it in Javascript.

As a whole, A well-formed API is not language-dependent. Usually it's XML or JSON (*see [API Data formats](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Data_formats), serialized PHP included*), for the XML case you can use the native PHP [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) (Guide [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-SimpleXML-With-PHP.html)) or [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org) library. just get & parse!

Comment: This is only available for .NET, I need it for PHP :(

Comment: currently only help for C# on that page, not for php.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you use definition of the selected words fro Google Define.
when you type define:beans, you would get a definition list of the word from google. This google search results come from various sources, but the first one is mostly correct.

You need to use Google Search API to search for this word, parse the XML and show the first result to the user.

You can use Google Search API from this [tutorial](http://www.fiftyfoureleven.com/weblog/web-development/programming-and-scripts/apis/google-search-api)

Quoting from the [Google Search API Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/)

> The Google AJAX Search API is a
>   Javascript library that allows you to
>   embed Google Search in your web pages
>   and other web applications. For Flash,
>   and other Non-Javascript environments,
>   the API exposes a raw RESTful
>   interface that returns JSON encoded
>   results that are easily processed by
>   most languages and runtimes.

---

Example:
define:cow to Google Search API would return back a lot of definitions.
Get the first element of the search result, parse it and show it next to the word.

Comment: Yes @Manish, this will be good because google has definitions of almost all words. Let me try it out will let you know if it works....

Comment: Yes. That is why am saying to use Google. Secondly when you done, please tell me whether it works or not. Of all Google APIs I have used, Search one was always left out.

Comment: Hi @Manish: I tried but `define:computer` query with `define` word is not working and not returning any results. I have checked this in there sample examples. Go to http://www.google.com/uds/samples/apidocs/tabbed.html and search `define:computer` and the click on web tab, its not giving any results. I think google not provided support for searching definitions from its search API

Comment: There was a SOAP Search API(http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/reference.html) which is not longer available. Google retired it. I was checking out this Developer Guide( http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje ) for Google AJAX Search API. Check whether it works

Comment: Google has since deprecated this API: "Note: The Google Web Search API has been officially deprecated as of November 1, 2010. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make per day will be limited. Therefore, we encourage you to move to Custom Search, which provides an alternative solution."